# Spring integration IP - omit carriage return (\r\n) at the end of message through sockets

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration, spring-messaging

When I send byte array to response channel I expect to send only that byte-array to the socket. For example, in spring integration ip.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "serviceChannel")
public byte[] service(byte[] byteArray) {
    return new byte[]{0,2,1,0};
}
```

I expect it to send

```
00, 02, 01, 00
```

But! This will also send two additional bytes to the stream

```
00, 02, 01, 00 , 0D, 0A
```

for end of message. I do NOT want to send those bytes, i.e. I'd like to omit them. How can this be achieved?

I suspect this has to do with how sockets interpret messages, but I did not find where this happens, no matter how I tried.

upd: I found the problem: Spring in my configuration uses class ByteArrayCrLfSerializer but I need to use ByteArrayRawSerializer. How can I do this?

Comment: Answerers don't get notifications of edits to the question; you should havew commented on my answer instead. You need to show your connection factory configuration (edit the question). If you are using XML configuration use `serializer="raw"` where `raw` is a `<bean>` with class `ByteArrayRawSerializer`. If you are using java configuration, simply set the serializer.

Comment: I did not see your answer at that point :) thanks

Comment: @GaryRussell I think that should be added to your answer, then it will be complete and I will be able to accept it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the Spring Integration documentation about serializers/deserializers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories).

You generally need some way to demarcate multiple messages in the stream. If the data inherently contains such information, you can use the `ByteArrayRawSerializer`, which will add no characters.

If you are using XML configuration use `serializer="raw"` where raw is a  with class ByteArrayRawSerializer. If you are using java configuration, simply set the serializer in the `@Bean`.

If you need to decode such messages with Spring Integration (and more than one is sent over the socket), you will need a custom deserializer.